# how to make to joysticks work at once on Arduino

Tags: arduino, joystick

I'm making my own controller using Arduino, and I am using 2 joysticks. the first joystick is to move around and the second is to look around. So when I use the first joystick that makes me walk around and then I would like to look around at the same time, but then it won't allow me to do both things at the same time.

I sat both of my joystick" controllers" into a void loop, and I think that's the reason why it doesn't work.

this is the first view i got:

```
#include <Mouse.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>
int Button1 = 7;  // øverste knap
int Button2 = 9;  // højre knap
int Button3 = 8;  // venstre knap
int Button4 = 10; // nederste knap

//joystick
int horzPin = A1;  // For x pin
int vertPin = A2;  // For y pin
int selPin = 2;  // For knap pin 

int vertZero, horzZero;  // Gemmer den indledende værdi for hver akse, normalt omkring 512
int vertValue, horzValue;  // Gemmer den nuværende værdi af akserne.
int mouseClickFlag = 0; // For musens knap Sprint

int MushorzPin = A3;  // For x pin
int MusvertPin = A4;  // For y pin
int MusselPin = 3;  // For knap pin

int MusvertZero, MushorzZero;  // Gemmer den indledende værdi for hver akse, normalt omkring 512
int MusvertValue, MushorzValue;  // Gemmer den nuværende værdi af akserne.
const int sensitivity = 200;  // Jo højere sensitivity der er jo langsommere er musen. Skulle være omkring 300
int MusmouseClickFlag = 0; // For musens knap


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Button1,INPUT);
  joyMovSetup();
  joystickMouseSetup();


}

void loop() {
btnHIGH();
btnLOW();
joyStickMouseEngine();
joyMovEngine();

}
```

this is for the mouse:

```
bool isPressed = false;

void joystickMouseSetup() {
  pinMode(MushorzPin, INPUT);  // Sætter pinsene til input
  pinMode(MusvertPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(MusselPin, INPUT);  // sætter knappen pin til input
  digitalWrite(MusselPin, HIGH);  // Sætter knap pin til høj fordi den ikke er trykket
  delay(1000);  // Lille kort pause for at få tingene til at fungere
  MusvertZero = analogRead(MusvertPin);  // Får start positionernes input
  MushorzZero = analogRead(MushorzPin);  // Joystikket skulle være neutralt når dette forekommer
}



void joyStickMouseEngine() {
  MusvertValue = analogRead(MusvertPin) - MusvertZero;  // Læser y aksens position
  MushorzValue = analogRead(MushorzPin) - MushorzZero;  // Læser x aksens position

  if (MusvertValue != 0)
    Mouse.move(0, MusvertValue/sensitivity, 0);  // Rykker musen på y aksen
  if (MushorzValue != 0)
    Mouse.move(MushorzValue/sensitivity, 0, 0);  // Rykker musen på x aksen

  if ((digitalRead(MusselPin) == LOW))  // Hvis joystick knappen er trykket
  {
   if (isPressed == true) {
      // Slukker knappen

    Keyboard.begin();
    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);  // Slipper shift
    delay(300);
     isPressed = false;
     return;

   } if (isPressed == false) {

    Keyboard.begin();
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);  // Slipper shift
    delay(300);
     isPressed = true;
     return;
   }


    }


  }
```

this is to move the player:

```
void joyMovSetup() {

  pinMode(horzPin, INPUT);  // Sætter pinsene til input
  pinMode(vertPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(selPin, INPUT);  // sætter knappen pin til input
  digitalWrite(selPin, HIGH);  // Sætter knap pin til høj fordi den ikke er trykket
  delay(1000);  // Lille kort pause for at få tingene til at fungere
  vertZero = analogRead(vertPin);  // Får start positionernes input
  horzZero = analogRead(horzPin);  // Joystikket skulle være neutralt når dette forekommer
}


void joyMovEngine() {

  int sensorValueX = analogRead(horzPin);
  int sensorValueY = analogRead(vertPin);

 if (sensorValueY < 20){
   Keyboard.press('w');
   delay(20);
   Keyboard.release('w'); 
    }

   else if(sensorValueX < 20){
    Keyboard.press('a');
    delay(20);
    Keyboard.release('a');
     }

   else if(sensorValueY > 1000){
    Keyboard.press('s');
    delay(20);
    Keyboard.release('s');
     }

   else if(sensorValueX > 1000){
    Keyboard.press('d');
    delay(20);
    Keyboard.release('d');
     }

  if ((digitalRead(selPin) == 0) && (!mouseClickFlag))  // Hvis joystick knappen er trykket
  {
    mouseClickFlag = 1;
    Keyboard.begin();
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);  // Trykker på shift
  }
  if ((digitalRead(selPin))&&(mouseClickFlag)) // Hvis joystick knappen ikke er trykket
  {
    mouseClickFlag = 0;
    Keyboard.begin();
    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);  // Slipper shift
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide implementation of both the functions? There might be blocking element somewhere

Comment: now I have sat all my code in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using interrupts. To do this tap the joystick's analog outputs and connect  them to interrupt enabled pins on your Arduino. Then set the interrupts to work either when it detects a rising input or a falling input.

You can also try FreeRTOS which will enable you read two joysticks at a time.